# Django form becomes invalid when position set to absolute or display set to none

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I wanted my upload file button to look different so I tried these two CSS one sets `display:none;` when file is uploaded and other is just setting it `position:absolute;`

My application works perfectly without CSS.
How can I solve this? Is there any other way to do it?

When the form  is submitted function in my views.py `form.is_valid()` returns False

**My First CSS :**

```css
input[type="file"] {
    opacity: 0; /* make transparent */
    z-index: -1; /* move under anything else */
    position: absolute; /* don't let it take up space */
}

input[type="file"]:focus + label {
    outline: 2px solid;  /* example focus style */
}
```

**My Second CSS:**

```css
.image-upload > input {
    display: none;
}
    
.image-upload img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```html
<div role="button" class="post-button image-upload" style="display: inline-block;border: none;border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;margin-left:5px;padding: 8px;">
    <label style="margin-bottom: 0;" for="id_picture">
        <img src="{% static "User/ART/Album.png" %}" alt="ProfilePic"/>
    </label>
    {{ post.content }}
    {{ post.picture }}
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```py
    class PostForm(forms.Form):
            content = forms.CharField()
            picture = forms.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `display:none` to the image input, as you upload the image, the image input doesn't have the value anymore. Therefore, that image will not be in the data when you submit the form. If you want to hide the image after uploading, try using `visibility:hidden and position:absolute` instead of `display:none`

Comment: When display:none; the HTML is removed therefore the file is not sent. That makes sense. But when position: absolute; it still fails. And setting the visibility to hidden will just make it not visible it will still occupy the same space. If you see how to Facebook upload button looks that what's I am trying to achieve